# svn migrating but dump part of the repository

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

I migrated the repository from server 1 to server 2 with svnadmin dump/load cycle, but I just dumped the latest 100 reversion(600~700). I found that the new repository's revision was from 1 to 100 instead of from 600 to 700. Here is the problem, after relocating the working copy, I update it and then I get "No such revision 700" error. It seems like the new repository version error?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to [generate empty padding revisions](http://www.timj.co.uk/2011/09/generating-emptypadding-revisions-in-an-svn-dump) for your SVN repo before loading dump:

> However, when this is loaded back into a new repository (`svnadmin load mynewrepo < repo.dump`), the revisions are renumbered starting at 1, so that what was revision 1234 becomes revision 1. This is undesirable, as I have existing bugs and changelogs referring to SVN revision numbers, so I created a small script ([svn-generate-empty-revisions](http://www.timj.co.uk/uploads/svn-generate-empty-revisions)) to create a number of empty revisions.
>
> In use, it’s most useful to splice its output into the start of an SVN dump, for example:
>
> ```
> svnadmin dump -r 1234:HEAD /path/to/repo > repo.dump
> # Extract the first few lines of the dump, which contain metadata
> head -n 4 repo.dump > repo-padded.dump
> # Splice in some empty "padding" revisions to preserve revision numbering
> # Note that the first revision is 1234, so we want 1233 empty revisions at start
> ./svn-generate-empty-revisions.sh 1233 >> repo-padded.dump
> # Add the rest of the original repository dump to the file
> tail -n +4 repo.dump >> repo-padded.dump
> ```

[svn-generate-empty-revisions](http://www.timj.co.uk/uploads/svn-generate-empty-revisions) script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Generate a number of empty revisions, for incorporation into an SVN dump file
# 2011 Tim Jackson <tim@timj.co.uk>

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: svn-generate-empty-revisions.sh NUMREVISIONS [TIMESTAMP]"
    exit 1
fi

timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000Z)
if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
    timestamp=$2
fi

for i in $(seq 1 $1); do
cat <<EOF
Revision-number: $i
Prop-content-length: 112
Content-length: 112

K 7
svn:log
V 38
This is an empty revision for padding.
K 8
svn:date
V 27
$timestamp
PROPS-END

EOF
done
```

Comment: make sure to make the new file executable: `chmod +x svn-generate-empty-revisions.sh`